# php variables for all functions?

Tags: php

I am creating a php page with alot of functions which require to use the same variable (session id).

Am I able to write $ID = $_SESSION['ID'];  and just use 'ID' in each function?

Rather than having to write $ID = $_SESSION['ID'];  in each function?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could do that but it would be better to create a `SessionManager` class that wraps session and exposes the values (like `ID`) via static `getXX` functions.

Try something like this:

```
class SessionManager {
    public static function getID() {
        return $_SESSION['ID'];
    }
}
```

then you can get the ID anywhere you want like this:

```
SessionManager::getID();
```

Comment: Thanks. Am I able to do something like this for using this code:
$getid = "SELECT `username` FROM `users` WHERE `ID` = '$ID'";
 $result=mysql_query($getid);
 $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
 $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
Rather than having to type that out everytime I need to access a row in the database? Thanks

Comment: If you're regularly retrieving a username based on your stored session user id, then why not also store the username in a session variable at login?

Comment: That was just an example, I am retrieving alot more information using the user ID, jus wondering if I could "load" all the rows then call a row in a function.

Comment: In that case I would probably write a function that retrieves all the information you want and returns it as an array.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to define a variable outside the function scope and be able to access it automatically from within functions, that's not possible.

You could define $ID = $_SESSION['ID']; outside of your function(s) scope, but then within each function you would have to add this:

> global $ID;

This would make the $ID variable accessible to the function.

This is not suggested, for numerous reasons. If I were you, I would just call $_SESSION['ID'] directly from within the function(s).

Answer (score 0):

if you declare `$ID` as a global variable you can use it in every function (after calling `global $ID`). but it will not update `$_SESSION['ID']`, if you want this too, you have to use references:

```
$ID = &$_SESSION['ID']
```

Comment: I don't think he's using classes

Comment: where was i talking about classes? ok, i see. public variable might be confusing. changed to global

Answer (score 0):

(Just in case you haven't already thought of it) You could also convert all session variables 'en masse' at the start of each function thusly:

```
foreach ($_SESSION as $key => $value) { 
    $$key = $value; 
}
```